# $A$ is an interval so $A$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, real-numbers

I want to prove that if $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval then $A$ is connected.

I found this proof, and I don't understand it essentially the ii)

> Suppose that $A$ is an interval but not connected, then there existe
>   two open sub-sets $B$ and $C$ such that $A=B\cup C$ and $B\cap C = \varnothing$.
>
> Let $x\in B$ and $y\in C$ such that $x<y$.
>
> The bounded set $B\cap[x,y]$ has a supremum witch we denote by $z$.
>
> i) If $z\in B,$ we have that $z<y,$ there exists $\delta <0$ such that
>   the interval $[z,z+\delta[\subset B\cap [x,y]$, which is a
>   contradiction.
>
> ii) If $z\in C$ there exists an interval $]z-\delta,z], (\delta>0)$ in
>   $C\cap [x,y]$, which is a contradiction.
>
> Then $z\notin B$ and $z\notin C$, which is impossible because
>   $[x,y]\subset A$.  It means that $A$ is connected.

I don't understand ii).  Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: $C$ is open. If $z\in C$, then $]z-\delta,z+\delta[ \cap A \subset C$ for some (hence all small enough) $\delta > 0$. Only the part $]z-\delta,z]$ is relevant for the proof. But $]z-\delta,z] \subset C$ implies that $z-\delta$ is an upper bound of $[x,y] \cap B$.

Comment: @DanielFischer why only $]z-\delta,z]$ is relevent ?

Comment: Because we're looking at $[x,y] \cap B$, of which $z$ is the supremum. So all of $[x,y]\cap B$ lies inside $[x,z]$, and if some $t\in ]z,z+\delta[$ is an upper bound for $[x,y]\cap B$, that is nothing new, and doesn't lead to a contradiction. Hence we focus on the other side of $z$, where we can get a contradiction.

Comment: @DanielFischer please in i) we obtain the contradiction by using that if $[z,z+\delta[\subset B\cap[x,y]$ then $\sup([z,z+delta[)<\sup(B\cap[x,y])$ so $z+\delta<z $ contradiction right ?

Comment: In $i)$, the contradiction is that $z$ is not an upper bound of $[x,y]\cap B$. In $ii)$, it is that $z$ is not the _least_ upper bound.